# C# Which .net version does my app require

Tags: c#

Sorry if its a stupid question. But I just wrote a tiny c# application and want to know which exact version of .net does my application requires .
Is there a way of knowing this , other than to uninstall and reinstalling all the .net versions on my PC.

my app btw is : http://www.ziddu.com/download/11874881/PerfectUpload.exe.html ( 14kb)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the VS IDE, right click on `yourProjectName`-->Properties-->Application-->Target Framework, and you will most likely see the framework version 3.5.

Comment: This is not necessary the correct way. Your application could very well be targeting .NET 3.5 in Visual Studio properties but if you never reference any of the .NET 3.5 assemblies in your application it could run perfectly fine with .NET 2.0 only installed.

Answer (score 2):

This application requires .NET 3.5 to run as it references `System.Xml.Linq` assembly and more specifically the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class in the `PostToImgur` method.

Comment: +1 for actually reflecting the exe (this can be achieved by using any reflection tool such as 'Red Gate's .Net Reflector')

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the required .NET version in the project settings!